# Adding prefix to file name when file is in directory - blueimp jQuery uploader

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, blueimp, uploader

is it possible to add prefix to file name, when file is in directory in blueimp jQuery uploader?
For example, I uploading

```
- text.txt 
--- directory1
--- file1.txt
```

and I want to autorename file1.txt to directory1-file.txt

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

jquery uploader send images to server ... 

any rename and save manipulation is happaning on the server ...

```
$temp = explode(".",$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$newfilename = rand(1,99999) . '.' .end($temp);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../img/imageDirectory/" . $newfilename;
```

this script sets file name as random number... you should write your logic for file name before save in php or any server side language (which you are using)

Comment: Ok, thanks, but I don't know how to recognize if uploaded thing have directories.

Comment: before you save file file dont have a directions it is saving in the tmp directory ...